# How do I allow the user to select the path for a file?

Tags: asp.net

In an application I'm working on, the users are prompted for the path of a file. This path will always point to a network drive, which the server has access to.

Currently, we use an asp:FileUpload control to accomplish this, drawing the path from the FileUpload's PostedFile.FileName property.

The problem is that the files the user is selecting from are locked down pretty severely. While the server has full access to them, the user only has permission to view the directory contents... They can't even open the files. This has worked fine up until now... But Windows 7 won't display these files in the file picker generated by FileUpload, so we need an alternative.

Notes:

- Looking for a way to get UI similar to the file open dialog already in place.
- The ability to view the client's local files (including the shared network drives) is a bonus, although listing the files through the server is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the permissions on these files.  If the users can't even open them, how can their terminal possibly upload them to a website?

I'm surprised this has ever worked.

If the user is simply supplying a path and not actually uploading the file you could have the server display the contents of the folder (in a list or whatever) and the user selects from that.

Answer (score 0):

So how about creating a file browser in a window, such that a user clicks "Pick File" which opens a new window showing the root contents of the network drive.  The user can then navigate round the directories to the file they want, finally clicking the file to "upload".

Use System.IO Directory.GetFiles to get the files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate out the two things. Here's an example prompt to convey the idea:

> Select a (file from your computer) OR (file from the server)

**Client Files**

You can use the standard file-upload control, that is fine.

**Server Files**

No user should be selecting files from your sever with the upload-file dialog. (Keep in mind that these dialog boxes allow right-click menus delete, copy, properties, etc and locked down or not, the user should not think they have this ability).

I don't think there are any controls that will "do-it-all" for you in this manner. I think your best bet is to make your own interface here.